# It's ok to ask the question about Travis CI?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

It's ok to ask the question about testing build with [Travis CI](http://www.travis-ci.org/)?
If yes, can we have tag for [travis-ci](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/travis-ci)?

Comment: But what if we are trying to test a Ansible or Chef workflow? (Hate to muddy the waters, but this is something I'm going to try this month)

Comment: @jrg "DevOps" does muddy the waters a bit, [as I've noted elsewhere](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271289/1068283). Just be sure your question is clearly _ops_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Travis CI isn't a service used by system administrators, but by programmers. It's therefore more appropriate to ask questions about it on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), where you'll find [hundreds of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/travis-ci) already.